# Unity interception and constructors

Tags: .net, unity-container, code-injection

I'd like to use interception with Unity, here is my code :

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.RegisterType<T, T>();
container.Configure<Interception>().SetDefaultInterceptorFor<T>(new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
return container.Resolve<T>();
```

If T is a class with a constructor with parameters (an an empty constructor) an exception is thrown when I call Resolve, else it works.
How can I intercept a type who has a non empty constructor ?

***Update***

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.RegisterType<T, T>();
container.Configure<InjectedMembers>().ConfigureInjectionFor<T>(new InjectionConstructor());
container.Configure<Interception>().SetDefaultInterceptorFor<T>(new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
return container.Resolve<T>();
```

This code works, but what if I'd like to use a constructor with argument ?

I've tried this :

```
public static T Resolve<T>(object param)
{
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
    container.RegisterType<T, T>();
    container.Configure<InjectedMembers>().ConfigureInjectionFor<T>(new InjectionConstructor(param));
    container.Configure<Interception>().SetDefaultInterceptorFor<T>(new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
    return container.Resolve<T>();
}
```

And in my code :

```
var service = Resolve<MyService>(4);
```

And I'm back with the same exception as earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](http://unity.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=3696)

Answer (score 1):

Unity will pick the constructor with the most arguments, so you have a few options:

1) Use configuration to specify using the no arg constructor like so:

```
Container.Configure<InjectedMembers>()
    .ConfigureInjectionFor<MyService>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

2) Annotate your object

```
public class MyService
{
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public MyService()
    {
    }

    public MyService(int arg1)
    {     
    }
}
```

3) override the DefaultUnityConstructorSelectorPolicy with your own that chooses the no arg constructor if it exists.

Comment: It works, but if I want to use MyService(int arg1), it throws (see my question, I've updated)

Answer (score 0):

Use the InjectionConstructor attribute as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440940.aspx#cnstrctinj_multiple).

Comment: I don't want to inject anything, I just want to create the interceptor which will call the empty constructor of T.